# Missing wsse:Security header in request

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis, soapui, rampart

I try to add rampart security to my axis 2 project using this [tutorial](http://jkrzemie.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/ws.pdf)   **page 19- 22**

SO everything seems fine but when I switch to soapUI perspective to try to  test the service 
the request which I'm proposed is :

```
soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:axis="http://axis2wstest">
 <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <axis:testws>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <axis:x>5</axis:x>
      </axis:testws>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**and it gives me as a response:**

```
faultstring>Missing wsse:Security header in request</fau
```

SO I add the security header and my request becomes  the same as the one written in the tutorial

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:axis="http://axis2wstest">
 <soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-
200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="123">
<wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-
200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <axis:testws>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <axis:x>5</axis:x>
      </axis:testws>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**but the response is the same**

```
soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <faultcode>wsse:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Missing wsse:Security header in request</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please don flag your questions with words like "urgent". Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add the security header directly to your request!

Click on **Aut** at the bottom left. Then you can enter your username/password there.
For more information see: http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/authenticating-soap-requests.html

As *Authorisation type* choose *Preemptive*. (Only in soapUI 4.5.1 as far as I know)

Comment: Thank you for your response! But I use soaUI plugin for eclipse. I click on the Aut menu and I've got these fields - Password (I write the password) , Username (I write the username) , Incoming WSS (it;s a dropdown and when I open it there is no opions ) and the same is with Outgoing WSS. It seems that i need to set my authorizatuon type but when I open in eclipse -Windows - Preferences - soapUi ; in https settings there is one field Authenticate preemptively and I click on the option - "Adds authentication info to outgoing requests " but nothing happens.

Comment: Leave *Incoming WSS* and *Outgoing WSS* blank and set only Username and Password. It should work.

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't work but thank you for your help. I appreciate it.